# Actionscript development - OS x vs windows

Tags: macos, development-environment

I have a mac sitting right next to my PC for photoshop/illustrator/flash development. However, though I am fully capable with a mac, I find the text navigation shortcuts non-standard and cumbersome to say the least. Recently I've taken to editing my actionscript files on my PC via a network share and then merely compiling the flash component on the mac. Workable as it is, I'd really like a better text editing environment on the mac so I wouldn't have to keep switching. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk) and [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org) on windows alone and save using the mac. Both of these tools are free. FlashDevelop uses C# I think (or some other .net) so it wouldn't work on the mac.

Comment: I downloaded the latest SDK and flashdevelop and tested it out. Works beautifully. Now I can do only the symbol development on the mac and do all AS in windows. AWESOME.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FlexBuilder (oh yeah, soon to be called [FlashBuilder](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder4/?sdid=EUHTC))?  It runs on both Windows and Mac.  It runs either as a standalone application built on Eclipse, or as a plugin to Eclipse.  As Eclipse is fairly full-featured, it works quite well and has a bit of refactoring support.

Comment: Actually, the only reason I develop on the Mac at all in flash is for mac only fonts that are often required. Is there a way to perhaps embed these fonts in a sub-swf and then develop on windows using them?

Comment: Yes. In the library, there is a new font item in the menu (beside new symbol and folder). Use this, enable linkage using flash.text.Font as the base class and go! Flash develop can explore that and show the fonts (as well as insert using the [Embed] code automatically).